# JAVA java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method toPath()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

В общем у меня есть проект, которые скачивает архив 7zip после проверяет есть ли он и тогда пытается его распаковать с помощью библиотеки rg.apache.commons.compress версии 1.17, но на это строке SevenZFile sevenZFile = new SevenZFile(file); выпадают следующие ошибки

```
Process: com.example.anton.fias_app, PID: 9102
              java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method toPath()Ljava/nio/file/Path; in class Ljava/io/File; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.io.File' appears in /system/framework/core-oj.jar)
                  at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.<init>(SevenZFile.java:108)
                  at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.<init>(SevenZFile.java:262)
                  at com.example.anton.fias_app.MainActivity$Unzippy.run(MainActivity.java:363)
```

Подскажите дураку, что делать, файл тот точно существует, в интернете натыкался на людей использующих данную библиотеку в android studio, но сам застрял на этом моменте.

```
    File myPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/FIAS_BD");
    File file = new File(myPath, "FIAS.7z");
    SevenZFile sevenZFile = new SevenZFile(file);
```

Comment: Разрешения в манифесте прописаны? На read/write?

Comment: @Jarvis_J конечно, я могу работать с файлами в приложении, но именно разархивировать не могу

Comment: Не всё, что написано на java можно использовать в Андроиде. Библиотека использует `java.nio.file.Path`, добавленный в Андроид только  с API26. Ну и соответственно метод `File.toPath()` тоже.